# larave convert arabic php to pdf by tcp pdf

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-9

I am trying to convert an html file that contains the Arabic language to pdf and I used tcp pdf

```
 public function generatePdf(){
    $users = User::all();
    $reportHtml = view('pdf.users', ['users' =>  $users])->render();
   return   PDF::HTML($reportHtml);
}
```

give me this error

```
 "message": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, Barryvdh\\Snappy\\PdfWrapper given, called in C:\\Users\\amrel\\Desktop\\topArt\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Response.php on line 72",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return pdf file directly. Try either

Option #1. Return response in application/pdf type:

```
 return Response::make(PDF::HTML($reportHtml), 200, [
        'content-type'=>'application/pdf',
 ]);
```

Option #2. From Laravel 5.2 you can return file in storage/ by just:

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

So you can save it to your storage and then return.

Option #3. You can send your pdf as downloadable file.

```
$pdf = PDF::HTML($reportHtml);
return $pdf->download('name.pdf');
```

Option #4. You can save pdf file to public storage and send url link to it and let the frontend decide.

Comment: dont work for me